# I can't bind with the IsExpanded property on my treeview

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to bind with an `IsExpanded` property, but without success so far. I need to know when one of the groups is expanded.

```
 <TreeView Grid.Row="1">

            <!--  Encontrados  -->
            <TreeViewItem
                FontWeight="Bold"
                IsExpanded="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Banco.Grupos}">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon
                            Width="20"
                            Foreground="Green"
                            Kind="Done" />
                        <TextBlock Text="ENCONTRADOS: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SaldoEncontrados, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='PT-BR'}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type model:Grupo}" ItemsSource="{Binding Transações}">
                                                     
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                               
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nome, StringFormat='{}{0}: '}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValorTotal, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='PT-BR'}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>                                
                            <DataTemplate>                                    
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <CheckBox
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding isEnabled}" />

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        Text="{Binding Transação.DataDaTransação, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}" />

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="2"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        Text="{Binding Transação.Historico}" />

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="3"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        FontWeight="Normal"
                                        Text="{Binding Transação.Valor, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='PT-BR'}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <!--  Não Encontrados  -->
            <TreeViewItem
                FontWeight="DemiBold"
                IsExpanded="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TransaçõesNãoEncontradas}">
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon
                            Width="20"
                            Foreground="Red"
                            Kind="Error" />
                        <TextBlock Text="NÃO ENCONTRADOS: " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SaldoNaoEncontrados, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='PT-BR'}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Coluna1" Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Text="{Binding DataDaTransação, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy'}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Text="{Binding Historico}" />
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                FontWeight="Normal"
                                Text="{Binding Valor, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='PT-BR'}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>
```

My group class:

```
public class Grupo
{
   
    public int Id { get; set; }       
    public int BancoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }                
    public List<Transações> Transações { get; set; }      
    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; }       
    public bool isExpanded { get; set; } = false;              
    public bool isZeroEnabled { get; set; }valores
}

public record Transações(int pk, int fk, bool isEnabled, OfxTransação Transação)
{
    public bool isEnabled { get; set; } = isEnabled;
}
```

XAML:

[image: RESULT]

**Could someone help me bind the treeview's IsExpanded property so that I can know when a "Group" is expanded.**

I created an example of my code: https://github.com/Foiolag/TreeviewExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `IsExpanded` property via `ItemContainerStyle`. Make sure to remove the explicite `IsExpanded="True"`

```
<!--  Encontrados  -->
<TreeViewItem FontWeight="Bold"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Banco.Grupos}">
    <TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </Style>
    </TreeViewItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**Hint 1:** This style will be inherited over all children, the application will also try to bind to the non existing `IsExpanded` property on your `Transações` object. This won't throw any exceptions, just binding errors. For the sake of consistency, I would rather implement the `IsExpanded` property on all children.

**Hint 2:** Your model classes are not *bindable* (do not notify property changes). If you change the properties after the view initialization, the view won't react to your changes. You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or use a base class like `BindableBase`. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844518/bindablebase-vs-inotifychanged). If the properties are intended for read-only use, better to make them read-only (remove setters).

**Hint 3:** Please avoid using special characters for your variables and class names

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` of the item container (in this case the `TreeViewItem`) is always the data item itself.
With this in mind you can setup the binding using a `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Setter Property="IsExpanded" 
          Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```